# How can I read data from specific location in .asc file using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have **.asc** file which has 1000's of rows. Each column in row is of the fixed length and separate by one space. I want to read email id column which is started from 296 position and ended at 326 position in a row.

Is there any way to read such data from **.asc** file?

Comment: What is an ".asc" file? What encoding is it using? Are the rows really a fixed width (in bytes) in the file? And do you want to read from a particular row, or all rows?

Comment: Absent an example or description of the file to be parsed, could you use [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) in [fixed width mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx)?  It's perfectly usable in c# despite being in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace.  See e.g. http://csharphelper.com/blog/2012/05/use-the-textfieldparser-class-to-easily-read-a-file-containing-fixed-width-data-in-c/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick for you. I am just reading the email ids in the file whatever extension file it might me, may it be txt or asc. Also it doesnt matter if the email address is locating at some other place instead of 296 or 326.

```
public void ExtractAllEmails()
{
    string datafrmAsc = File.ReadAllText(YourASCFile); //read File 
    Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(datafrmAsc);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Match emailMatch in emailMatches)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(emailMatch.Value);
    }
    File.WriteAllText(SomeTxtFile, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Another way of saying thanks on SO is by upvoting the answer. Well, Happy to help and you are most welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is large text file, you can do something like this:

```
        List<string> emailsList = new List<string>();
        int startIndex = 295;
        int endIndex = 325;

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open("c:\\test.asc", FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
                string line = string.Empty;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    emailsList.Add(line.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).Trim());
                }

         }
```

Comment: Thank you Nino. Though earlier code is resolved my problem. But still you code is also bit optimized. I have different way implementation so will use your code as well.

Comment: Glad i could help. My approach is a bit more optimized (it reads file line by line, while @Mohit Shrivastava loaded all text at one) because you stated that there are thousands of lines.

Comment: actually I have batch size defined for processing so your code fit in my requirement. While optimization meant here not performance but processing approach.